# Using Windows REN to insert text into a filename, maintaining the rest of the name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

I'm currently trying to use the REN command to add text in the middle of a filename, while maintaining the rest of the filename.

Example:

`testfile_2018-11-14-06-06-23.pdf` -> `testfile_ABCD_2018-11-14-06-06-23.pdf`

The last six digits are subject to change, so I need to represent them with wildcards.

Currently, I have the following:

`REN testfile_2018-11-14*.pdf testfile_ABCD_2018-11-14*.pdf`

Result is:
`testfile_ABCD_2018-11-146-23.pdf`

The last six digits are not being maintained, and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: PowerShell with string splitting or regex would be ideally suited to address this.  Any reason you're not using it?

Comment: As @Squashman says in his answer, this cannot be done with REN alone. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/a/475875/109090) at SuperUser for an explanation of exactly what can and cannot be done.

Comment: @dbenham, how about a [JREN.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081&start=45#p58158) answer. I know it is kind of overkill for this task but would be a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure it cannot be done with a simple `REN` command. You can however use the power of the `FOR /F` command to manipulate the file name.

From the command prompt you can run this.

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %G IN ('dir /a-d /b "testfile_2018-11-14*.pdf"') do ren "%G_%H" "%G_ABCD_%H"
```

This finds the file and then splits the file name by the underscore.  It then renames it with the extra string in the new file name.

If you are going to run this in a batch file you must double the percent symbols.

Answer (score 2):

If we're offering alternative solutions to REN, here are a few ways in PowerShell:

String Splitting:

```
## Get a System.IO.FileInfo object to the file
$f = Get-Item path-to-the-testfile

## Split up the name by the underscore so the zeroth entry is 'testfile' and the first entry is the remaining name
$s = $f.Name.Split("_")

## Use String tokenization to recombine the different parts in the desired order during the rename
Rename-Item $f.FullName ("{0}\{1}_{2}_{3}" -f $f.DirectoryName, $s[0], 'ABCD', $s[1])
```

String Replace:

```
## Get a System.IO.FileInfo object to the file
$f = Get-Item path-to-the-testfile

## Use string replace to fix the name during the rename operation
Rename-Item $f.FullName ($f.FullName.Replace('testfile_', 'testfile_ABCD_'))
```

Using regex is possible but is probably overly complicated if you're not familiar with the above methods.